# I reinstalled Ubuntu (by formatting the Ubuntu location), then windows 10 disappeared from dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

It was installed on the 1TB hard drive here. I can see the program files, but not the boot screen. So I can't boot Windows.

[Windows Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtbQr.jpg)

I did the suggested solutions in the initial research but it doesn't work, so I'm asking again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then reboot.

If that doesn't work, post the output of these commands:

```
sudo lsblk --fs
inxi -Fxxxrz
```